# Dplyr mutate many columns with each new column conditional on two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame is like the simple one below with many more columns and rows.

My goal is to add a new column  for every "model" based on some ifelse() output using the matching *pval* and *value_IC* column.

Here, models are linear, beta and emax.

The closest problem I have found so far was here

https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-mutate-at-mutate-if-multiple-columns-using-condition-on-other-column-outside-vars-dplyr/17506/2

where there is always the same "second" column used.

```
data <- data.frame(pval.linear.orig = c(0.01, 0.06, 0.02),
                   pval.beta.orig = c(0.06, 0.02, 0.01),
                   pval.emax.orig = c(0.03, 0.01, 0.07),
                   value_IC.linear.orig = c(-5, NA, -4),
                   value_IC.beta.orig = c(NA, NA, -10),
                   value_IC.emax.orig = c(NA, -11, NA))

  pval.linear.orig pval.beta.orig pval.emax.orig value_IC.linear.orig value_IC.beta.orig value_IC.emax.orig
1             0.01           0.06           0.03                   -5                 NA                 NA
2             0.06           0.02           0.01                   NA                 NA                -11
3             0.02           0.01           0.07                   -4                -10                 NA
```

If I only wanted it for one model, let's say beta, I would do this:

```
library(dplyr)
data_new <- data %>% mutate(conv.beta.orig = case_when(
  pval.beta.orig > 0.025~ NA,
  pval.beta.orig <= 0.025 & !(is.na(value_IC.beta.orig))  ~ TRUE,
  pval.beta.orig <= 0.025 & is.na(value_IC.beta.orig) ~ FALSE)) 

data_new

  pval.linear.orig pval.beta.orig pval.emax.orig value_IC.linear.orig value_IC.beta.orig value_IC.emax.orig conv.beta.orig
1             0.01           0.06           0.03                   -5                 NA                 NA             NA
2             0.06           0.02           0.01                   NA                 NA                -11          FALSE
3             0.02           0.01           0.07                   -4                -10                 NA           TRUE
```

to get the *conv.beta.orig* column. The column name does not have to be exactly in this format.

My problem now is to do so with all models I have each using the pval.MODEL.orig and value_IC.MODEL.orig column as above.

Thank you very much for your help!
This is the first question I ever posted, let me now if I should reformulate something / missed something or didn't spot this problem in case it already exists / etc.

Comment: Do you want to apply the same conditions, then use `mutate_at`

Comment: Yes, it will always be the same conditions.  I just can't figure out how to exactly apply it with regard to using those two other columns each time.